Why is VSCode not recognizing imports that aren't top level imports?
I have the following code in a Python file in VSCode:
# These work just fine
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

# These have an error
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.utils import resample

The error I'm getting is:
Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)
Import "sklearn.utils" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

I have verified that TensorFlow is installed correctly, and that I'm using the correct Python in VSCode. Also if I wasn't it seems like it would fail to resolve the first one also.
I think the issue is that when you have those nested (not top level) imports, VSCode isn't working properly.
I read here that there is an option called python.analysis.packageIndexDepths in settings, which I have verified looks correct to me:
"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
    {
        "name": "sklearn",
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "matplotlib",
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "scipy",
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "django",
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "flask",
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "fastapi",
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "tensorflow",
        "depth": 4,
        "includeAllSymbols": true
    }
],

I have tried reloading the window as well without any success.
Finally, I have tried to remove includeAllSymbols, but that didn't seem to make any difference as well.
One more note, not that I think it makes a difference, but I'm using VSCode through SSH Connect to Host mode. All my extensions I reinstalled after doing that, so the Python extension does look to be enabled and working.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Edit:
Based on the comments, after adding # pyright: strict to the very top of my file and running pip install types-tensorflow that fixed a lot of problems, but created a lot more errors and warnings in my script that I'll have to go back and fix.
However, I'm still getting a few import errors.
I left this out of my original code since I was trying to create a minimal example, but from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam was failing with the same error before, those things I did fixed it.
However for from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential the error has changed to:
Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingModuleSource)

The error for from sklearn.utils import resample has changed to:
Import "sklearn.utils" could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingModuleSource)

Type of "resample" is partially unknown
  Type of "resample" is "(*arrays: Any, replace: bool = True, n_samples: int | signedinteger[_8Bit] | signedinteger[_16Bit] | signedinteger[_32Bit] | signedinteger[_64Bit] | None = None, random_state: RandomState | int | signedinteger[_8Bit] | signedinteger[_16Bit] | signedinteger[_32Bit] | signedinteger[_64Bit] | None = None, stratify: ndarray | DataFrame | Any | Buffer | _SupportsArray[dtype[Any]] | _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]] | bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes | _NestedSequence[bool | int | float | complex | str | bytes] | None = None) -> (list[ndarray] | None)" Pylance (reportUnknownVariableType)

Edit 2:
It looks like running pip install scikit-learn fixed the first (could not be resolved from source) issue, but the partially unknown issue is still happening.

Do you have types-tensorflow installed? Tip: Put # pyright: strict at the very top of the file to see all errors.

As for sklearn.utils, I failed to reproduce the problem. sklearn stubs are bundled with Pylance, so it should have been able to resolve the module.

For tensorflow imports you could try import tensorflow.python.keras.models instead of tensorflow.keras.models.I was unable to reproduce issue on sklearn so please make sure scikit-learn is installed as sklearn package is deprecated.

@InSync Thank you so much for your comments. I think that got me closer to resolving this, but didn't resolve it completely. I added an edit to my OP explaining what happened after I did all of your suggestions.

# pyright: strict is a type checker directive; it tells Pyright/Pylance to enable strict mode, in which it will show errors that the average user normally doesn't care, including "partially unknown type" errors. This is useful for debugging; if strict static typing isn't your goal, you can just remove the directive.

@InSync Got it. It still seems like that reportMissingModuleSource error for tensorflow is an issue tho. Because it just shows Incomplete in my code when I hover over the variable.

reportMissingModuleSource is when a module's type stubs can be found (via types-tensorflow) but not the actual code (the module tensorflow.keras.models itself). I am unfamiliar with Tensorflow, so that's all I know.
